# Calculate the percentage in Matlab

Tags: matlab, decimal, percentage

I want to calculate the percentage of accuracy. I have the code below. But it give unexpected output like this "The accuracy is 2.843137e+01x37".
While expected result is "The accuracy is 28.43%"

```
y %Amount of correct data
j %Amount of all data
a = 'The accuracy is %dx%d.';
percent = '%.0f%%';
format short
acc = 100 * double(y/j);
sprintf (a,acc)
```

How to fix it?

Any help would be so much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What is `y`, what is `j` and what is their type? Probably you want to do the explicit cast to double before the division.

Comment: By the way, 2.843e+01 == 28.43?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have what you expected, just put it together the right way.

The correct format specifier for 28.43% is `%.2f%%`. This gives you two digits after the decimal point and adds the %-sign at the end. You have that defined in the variable `percent`, except that `.0` should be `.2` for two digits as you have written in the expected result. If you look closely, you'll realize that `percent` is never used.

Let's come to the conclusion. Change the format specifier to the following:

```
a = 'The accuracy is %.2f%%';
```

That's all you need to do. The line defining `percent` can be omitted as well as `format short` unless you need this for something later on.

Something important regarding the cast to double: What you currently have just casts the result. If *necessary*, do the cast *individually* to `y` and/or `j` *before the division*. Probably you don't need any casting in your case.

---

*The whole code with an assumption for `y` and `j` is:*

```
y = 28.43137;   %// Amount of correct data
j = 100;        %// Amount of all data

a = 'The accuracy is %.2f%%';
acc = 100 * (y/j);                    %// no cast
% acc = 100 * (double(y)/double(j));  %// with cast
sprintf(a,acc);
```

*Output:*

```
ans =
The accuracy is 28.43%
```

Comment: @AnaAin You're welcome. One more note: I assume that the cast to double is not needed. I extended my answer to show the correct way to cast *if it is needed*.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
a = 'The accuracy is %f.';
acc = 100 * double(y/j);
sprintf (a,acc)
```